# Update no está actualizando tabla en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, android

He estado tratando de actualizar mi tabla usando PHP, pero al ejecutar el código no se actualizan los datos. El código en PHP es el siguiente

```
<?php
     include 'conexion.php';
     $codigo=$_POST['codigo'] ?? "";
     $consulta="update agregados set estado='0' where codigo='".$codigo."'";
     mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die (mysqli_error());
     mysqli_close($conexion);  
?>
```

Cabe aclarar que estoy haciendo un app en Android la cual tiene un ListView en el cual debo poder eliminar un item en especifico de ese listado (con conexión de BD mediante PHP). El código de la app Android es el siguiente:

```
public class ListadoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String URL_broches = "http://192.168.43.3/WS/listarSeleccionados.php";
    private static final String URL_eliminar = "http://192.168.43.3/WS/eliminar.php";
    private static final String URL_eliminarTodo = "http://192.168.43.3/WS/eliminarTodo.php";
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Broches> lista;
    Column_ListAdapter adapter;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        lista = new ArrayList<>();
        loadSeleccionados();

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVolver2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*Intent i = new Intent(ListadoActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("broches", getIntent().getStringExtra("broches"));
                startActivity(i);*/
                //startActivity((new Intent(ListadoActivity.this, InfoActivity.class).putExtra("broches", lista.get(position))));
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVaciar);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(ListadoActivity.this)
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)
                        .setTitle("Eliminar todo")
                        .setMessage("¿Desea eliminar todo el listado?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                eliminarTodo();
                                recreate();
                                finish();
                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                startActivity(getIntent());
                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No",null)
                        .show();
            }
        });

        ViewGroup headerView = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cabecera, listView, false);
        listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(ListadoActivity.this)
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)
                        .setTitle("Eliminar producto")
                        .setMessage("¿Desea eliminar el producto?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Broches broches =  lista.get(position-1);
                                //Broches broches = (Broches) listView.getItemAtPosition(position-1);

                                String codigo = broches.getCodigo();
                                eliminarProducto(codigo);
                                recreate();
                                finish();
                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                startActivity(getIntent());
                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                        .show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadSeleccionados(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_broches, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
               Broches bro = null;
                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject broche = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        bro = new Broches();
                        bro.setCodigo(broche.getString("codigo"));
                        bro.setDescripcion(broche.getString("descripcion"));
                        bro.setPrecio(broche.getDouble("precio"));
                        bro.setCantidad(broche.getInt("cantidad"));
                        lista.add(bro);
                    }
                    
                    adapter = new Column_ListAdapter(ListadoActivity.this, R.layout.list_adapter_view, lista);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void eliminarProducto(final String codigo){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_eliminar, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
                params.put("codigo",codigo);
                return super.getParams();
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void eliminarTodo(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_eliminarTodo, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
                //final String codigo;
                //params.put("codigo",codigo);
                return super.getParams();
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Verificaste que la variable `$codigo` tenga el dato correcto y no sea vacío??

Comment: Hola, probé con var_dump y me devuelve string(0) ""

Comment: y que error te da el "die" ?

Comment: tienes un condicional en el que, si no llega por POST el valor de "codigo", lo pones a vacio. Puede ser que no estes enviando correctamente (por post) el parametro codigo?

Comment: Si te devuelve `string(0)` es porque esta llegando un vacío esa es la razón por la que no te actualiza. Como te dice @Jakala el problema parece estar en el post. ;)

Comment: El die no me está dando errores, la variable "codigo", en ningún momento la pongo en vacío

Comment: en la linea `$codigo=$_POST['codigo'] ?? "";`, si codigo no esta definido en post, entonces asignas el valor a vacio.

Comment: Si el valor del código es **esencial**, como parece ser, deberías condicionar la ejecución de la consulta a que ese dato no esté vacío, con algo como: `if ($codigo) { //Aquí creas la variable $consulta y ejecutas el UPDATE } else { echo "Datos incompletos"; }` De todos modos en tu programa faltan controles. Una consulta `UPDATE` podría fallar si viola alguna restricción, o puede parecer que funcionó sin hacer nada. Por ejemplo, si mandas a actualizar con el mismo dato que ya existe, la consulta no daría error, pero no actualizaría nada. Eso se puede controlar con el número de filas afectadas.

Answer (score 1):

En tu programa hay varias malas prácticas y problemas de seguridad. Voy a enumerar cada cosa en su orden de aparición:

1. No incluyas nada hasta **no estar segura de necesitarlo**
2. Controla las **columnas esenciales** de tus tablas y condiciona tus consultas SQL a que los valores para esas columnas tengan valor. En este caso, deberías condicionar la consulta a que `$codigo` tenga datos. Lo mismo deberías hacer en cualquier consulta para columnas que tengan restricciones `NOT NULL`.
3. Controla **todo**. La tarea de un programador es prever todo lo que podría salir mal. Por ejemplo, ¿qué pasa si no hay conexión? La base de datos puede estar caída y tu código no controla nada al respecto.
4. Evita **ejecutar directamente consultas que contengan datos proporcionados por el usuario**. Un usuario mal intencionado podría manipular esos datos y causar graves daños en el sistema. Es lo que se conoce como *Inyección SQL*. Para prevenirlo deberías usar consultas preparadas.
5. Evita **mostrar mensajes internos del manejador de base de datos**. Esos mensajes revelan a veces información sensible que podría ser explotada por hackers. Aquí los hemos dejado porque interesa mantenerlos en fase de desarrollo. Pero para programas finales deberían ser cambiados por mensajes personalizados.
6. Haz un **control real** de lo que ha ocurrido en una consulta. **En el caso de `UPDATE`**, para conocer lo que ocurrió con esa consulta se debería controlar el número de filas afectadas. Es la única forma de saber si una consulta de este tipo fue efectiva o no. A veces interesa realmente saber si se actualizaron filas o no.

El código, aplicando todo lo dicho, quedaría así (he puesto comentarios para que se entienda lo que he hecho):

```
<?php
    $codigo=$_POST['codigo'] ?? "";
    /*
        $codigo es esencial, por tanto aquí todo depende de él
        si la variable está vacía nada se ejecutará, ni siquiera el
        include del archivo de conexión 
    */
     if ($codigo) {
       include 'conexion.php';
       if($conexion) {
           /*
              Esto es una consulta preparada, en lugar de la variable 
              ponemos un marcador ?  y pasamos la variable con un método
              que evitará que te inyecten código
           */
           $consulta="update agregados set estado='0' where codigo=?";
           if ( $stmt=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$consulta) ) {
               mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $codigo);
               /*
                  Verificamos que no haya error al ejecutar el UPDATE 
                  por ejemplo filas duplicadas
               */
               if ( mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) ){ 
                 $outPut="Filas actualizadas: ".mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
               }else{
                 $outPut="Error ejecutando la consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
               }
           } else {
               $outPut="Error preparando la consulta: ".mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
           }
           mysqli_close($conexion);  
       } else {
          $outPut="No hay conexion";
       }
     } else {
       $outPut="Código vacío o no válido";      
     }
     /*
        En toda la lógica fuimos recogiendo en $outPut
        lo que haya podido ocurrir, para informar al usuario
     */
     echo $outPut;
?>
```

No es el programa simple (e ingenuo) del principio. Estamos ante un código robusto, que controla todos los posibles errores, dando en cada caso una respuesta. Este programa te dirá sí o sí lo que ocurre, no te dejará en el limbo, sin saber por qué ha fallado. Es algo esencial, porque los programas están generalmente destinados a usuarios que no podrán intervenir en el código para arreglar lo que el programador haya hecho mal. Y si el usuario se ha equivocado, mandando un código nulo o vacío, el programa le dirá que debe suministrar un código válido.

Por otra parte, el código también es seguro contra usuarios maliciosos.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120107/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-update-no-esta-actualizando-tabla-en-php).